# How to convert a Heic image file to a Jpeg or Png in Angular for ngx-image-cropper to use?

Tags: angular, base64, jpeg, heic

**Question** - ngx-image-cropper doesn't accept Heic image files as it's '[imageChangedEvent]' input so how would I convert an Heic image file to a Jpeg or Png in Angular/typescript?

FYI - I'm loading images into ngx-image-cropper and it looks like it doesn't except Heic image files. Ngx-image-cropper is emitting a loadImageFailed() emitter if the file type is 'image/heic'.

Currently I open image files with a fileChangeEvent() from an input element, I guess I want to convert to a jpeg or png so that I can pass it to a the ngx-imge-cropper imageChangedEvent or it's base64 input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one NPM package named ***Heic2any*** you can use this for image conversion.

This answer might help you with image conversion.
Please take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64695145/11004482)

**Heic2any:**

[Official doc](https://alexcorvi.github.io/heic2any/)

[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heic2any)

Comment: Ya I saw that, I'm just wondering if there's a better solution? Do you know if it's possible to load the heic into a canvas and then extract the dataurl from the canvas as a jpeg?